# Laravel route partially work on my installation and stopping route

Tags: php, laravel

I found a strange mistake in laravel web.php (route)

This line I add about a month ago and it works fine...

```
Route::redirect('/expired-domains-database', '/deleted-domains-database');
```

this http://whoisdatacenter.in/expired-domains-database redirect to https://whoisdatacenter.in/deleted-domains-database

in same file  I add below line and it wont work

```
Route::redirect('/whois-coupon-code', '/');
```

this https://whoisdatacenter.in/whois-coupon-code is not redirecting to https://whoisdatacenter.in

any idea where I am doing wrong?

full code

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\TableController;
use App\Http\Controllers\jashan;
use App\Http\Controllers\MessagerController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
Route::get('/', [TableController::class, 'home']);

Route::get('/date/{date}', [TableController::class, 'date']);
Route::get('/country/{id?}', [TableController::class, 'country']);
Route::get('/tld/{id?}', [TableController::class, 'tld']);
Route::get('/registrar/{id?}', [TableController::class, 'registrar']);
Route::get('/deleted-domains-database', [TableController::class, 'expired']);
Route::get('/expiring-domains-database', [TableController::class, 'expiring']);
Route::get('/complete-whois-database', [TableController::class, 'complete']);
Route::get('/leads-generation', [TableController::class, 'cleaned']);
Route::get('/active-domains-database', [TableController::class, 'active']);
Route::get('/newly-registered-whois-database', [TableController::class, 'newly']);
Route::view('api-documentation','api');
Route::get('/free-database', [TableController::class,'free_database']);
Route::view('/privacy-policy','privacy-policy');
Route::view('/term-of-services','term-of-services');
Route::view('support','support');
Route::view('about-us','about_us');
Route::view('amit', 'amit');
Route::view('rajdeep', 'rajdeep');
Route::get('/deepak/{id?}', [TableController::class, 'deepak']);

Route::get('/jashan', [tablecontroller::class, 'jashan']);

Route::redirect('unique:insur_docs', '/tld');

Route:: get('a',[TableController::class,'a']);

/* Added by Amit 2021-04-05 09:00 pm */


Route::redirect('/tld-specific-whois-database/', '/tld');
Route::redirect('/tld-list/', '/tld');
Route::redirect('/tos/', '/term-of-services');
Route::redirect('/domain-registrar-specific-whois-database/', '/registrar');
Route::redirect('/contact-us/', '/portal/submitticket.php?step=2&deptid=1');
Route::redirect('/newly-registered-domains-list/', '/newly-registered-whois-database');
Route::redirect('/newly-registered-domains/', '/newly-registered-whois-database');
Route::redirect('/new-registered-whois-data/', '/newly-registered-whois-database');
Route::redirect('/newly-registered-domain-list/', '/newly-registered-whois-database');
Route::redirect('/cleaned-whois-database/', '/leads-generation');
Route::redirect('/historical-whois-database/', '/leads-generation');
Route::redirect('/cleaned-whois-data/', '/leads-generation');
Route::redirect('/keywords-whois-data/', '/leads-generation');
Route::redirect('/free/', '/free-database');
Route::redirect('/whois-database-download-free/', '/free-database');
Route::redirect('/free-india/', '/free-database');
Route::redirect('/newly-registered-domains-database-free/', '/free-database');
Route::redirect('/expiring-domain-names/', '/expiring-domains-database');
Route::redirect('/dropped-deleted-domains/', '/expired-domains-database');
Route::redirect('/france-whois-database/', '/country/70');
Route::redirect('/united-kingdom-whois-database/', '/country/218');
Route::redirect('/united-arab-emirates-whois-database/', '/country/217');
Route::redirect('/new-zealand-whois-database/', '/country/146');
Route::redirect('/australia-whois-database/', '/country/13');
Route::redirect('/country-specific-whois-database/', '/country');
Route::redirect('/whois-database/', '/complete-whois-database');
Route::redirect('/historic-whois-data/', '/complete-whois-database');
Route::redirect('/historical-whois-data/', '/complete-whois-database');
Route::redirect('/historic-whois-data/all-countries-whois-data/', '/complete-whois-database');

Route::redirect('/active-domains-list/', '/active-domains-database');
Route::redirect('/sample/', '/');
Route::redirect('/india-whois-database/', '/country/91');
Route::redirect('/united-states-whois-database/', '/country/219');
Route::redirect('/trial/', '/');
Route::redirect('/domain-data-provider/', '/');
Route::redirect('/payment-options/', '/');
Route::redirect('/faqs/', '/');
Route::redirect('/category/discount-coupons/', '/');
Route::redirect('/buy-whois-database/', '/');
Route::redirect('/pricing/', '/');
Route::redirect('/sample', '/');
Route::redirect('/yearly-whois-database/', '/');
Route::redirect('/billing/clientarea.php', '/');
Route::redirect('/how-to-download-complete-whois-database/', '/');
Route::redirect('/whois-database-provider/', '/');
Route::redirect('/daily-domain-data/', '/');
Route::redirect('/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/images.jpeg', '/');
Route::redirect('/domain-database-download/', '/');
Route::redirect('/whoisds/', '/');
Route::redirect('/whoxydata/', '/');
Route::redirect('/whois-database-india', '/country/91');
Route::redirect('/expired-domains-database', '/deleted-domains-database');

// added by deepak
Route::redirect('/whois-coupon-code', '/');
Route::redirect('/gonook', '/');
Route::redirect('/whoisdb', '/');
Route::redirect('/dialme24', '/');
Route::redirect('/allwhois', '/');
Route::redirect('/domainregistrationdatabase', '/');
Route::redirect('/whoisget', '/');
Route::redirect('/articles', '/');
Route::redirect('/domaindata365', '/');
Route::redirect('/internationalwhoisdatabase', '/');
Route::redirect('/whoxydata', '/');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try move `Route::get('/', [TableController::class, 'home']);`  to the bottom of the file.

Use

```
$route = Route::current();
$name = Route::currentRouteName();
$action = Route::currentRouteAction();
```

to check the current route.